# Change Vim's Syntastic to use a certain checker based on file extension?

Tags: vim, jshint, eslint, syntastic

I have vim's syntastic installed properly along with eslint and jshint. I prefer jshint for most of my javascript programming. However, I'm starting to learn React, and would like to use eslint with syntastic (eslint has superior/proper linting for react).

Is it possible to set vim to use jshint for *.js files, and eslint for *.jsx files?

I see from :help syntastic-checkers that react gets lumped in javascript. Chaining the linters is not what I want, either.

Comment: You could try `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.jsx let b:syntastic_checkers = ['eslint']`.  This may or may not work with `syntastic_check_on_open`, depending on the order your Vim chooses to run `autocmd`s (the order is not well-defined).  If it still runs `jshint` on open you might add a similar `autocmd` for `*.js`, and leave `g:syntastic_javascript_checkers` unset.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to an answer, @lcd047!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it! You were very close @lcd047, but your comment lead me down the right path! To enable `eslint` on only *jsx files, putting the following in my `.vimrc` works:

`au BufEnter *.jsx let b:syntastic_checkers = ['eslint']`

In my case, syntastic will use `jshint` on javascript by default even if a checker is not set in `.vimrc`. Setting the above works even if `g:syntastic_javascript_checkers` is unset or even if it is set, in my case, to jshint.

Comment: An `autocmd` on `BufEnter` will definitely not work with `syntastic_check_on_open`.  Feel free to ignore me though.

Comment: @lcd047, maybe I found a bug then? I still get the same behavior as described above: jshint on javascript files, and eslint on *.jsx files. I also have `g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1` in my vimrc. I have the two checkers installed globally via npm.

As the main contributor to syntastic, I do appreciate your help. Forgive me if I seemed a bit pedagogic (that's my teacher training and my own inexperience/excitement showing).

Comment: The bug is in your understanding of what is supposed to happen. `check_on_open` runs on `BufRead`, and `BufRead` is applied before `BufEnter`.  `b:syntastic_checkers` will be unset the _first_ time you run `check_on_open` in active mode.